# wso2 proxy vfs to vfs - two dependant files

Tags: file, batch-file, wso2, vfs

We have requirement to monitor input folder where we are expecting some batch files. The source sends some large files eg : xxx123.dat followed by xxx123.end file to indicate complete transfer.
How can we configure wso2 vfs proxy to start reading this .dat only after the corresponding  .end file is read and also send these to destination folder first .dat and then .end in order .

Answer (score 0):

As fas as I know, you can't do that by default.

But have a look to *repository/conf/axis2/**axis2.xml*** : transport receiver for VFS is implemented in *org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.**VFSTransportListener***

You can extend this class in order to implement your need : a method named **pool** is invoked when time as come to scan the directory...